# Should I load HTML with Inline JS or the Script that Defines the JS First?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have run into an interesting problem. I'm trying to understand when to load inline js functions. What should be defined first? The html that calls the function, or the function itself?

I should note that I'm using babel to use es6 classes and modules. Fairly confident that is not the problem.

I've run into this with the Facebook SDK. I'm unsure of the order of the elements that Facebook needs to load. I've included them in the recommended order but it doesn't recognize the onlogin hook inside of the facebook login button.

My html (jade) looks like this:

```
script(src='assets/js/bundle.js')

fb:login-button(scope='public_profile,email', onlogin='checkLoginState();')
#status
```

Inside of bundle I have

```
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    testAPI();
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into this app.';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log into Facebook.';
  }
}

function checkLoginState() {
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId      : '###########',
    cookie     : true,
    xfbml      : true,
    version    : 'v2.6'
  });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });
};

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function testAPI() {
...
}
```

However, If I click on the Facebook login, it will not fire the `checkLoginState` function and it returns undefined.

This is exactly the flow that they [prescribe](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web).

Alternatively, what is the order that this needs to be loaded in?

Attempted Solutions:

1. Reversing the order. I've tried loading the script after the button
2. I've tried changing the fbAsyncInit to an iife.
3. I've tried bypassing the onlogin function entirely but the response comes back as unknown.
4. New approach - manually build button and use a `document.addEventListener`

Comment: i suggest number 4, here´s a tutorial: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: Pretty sure it needs to be just `onlogin='checkLoginState'`, not an actual function _call_ at that point.

Comment: @CBroe I tried that and same error.

Comment: @luschn Thanks - that worked! Still not sure why it wasn't getting loaded but probably it's something to do with async.